# Trailing space on reputation score tooltip

Tags: bug, reputation, tooltips

There is a trailing space after "reputation score" in the title attribute for the reputation score: `title="reputation score "`.

> [image]

First noticed on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but it also happens here or SO. Probably on all SE sites.

If there was a minor-bug tag, I would've used this.

**Edit:** Also appearing here:

[image]

Comment: That's not flair. anyway, bug is a bug, no matter if small or big.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Okay, I thought the _thing_ underneath questions/answers is also called flair.

Comment: Anyway, the space is there because when the rep is abbreviated then the tooltip will show the full score: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9TAJb.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard So this is possibly by design? For simplicity reasons maybe.

Comment: The code that generates this is something like `title="reputation score $score"` then replace `$score` with actual rep if needed, otherwise blank. Fix will be `title="reputation score$score"` then add space before the actual score... anyway up to the devs to decide whether to fix it or not. :)